# Cmake : post-package step

Tags: cmake

I'm looking for a way to execute a code after the packaging is done.

I tried to add a custom target that was depending on the PACKAGE target generated.
That looks like it does not work, here's cmake error:

```
CMake Error: The inter-target dependency graph contains the following strongly connected        component (cycle):
"ALL_BUILD" of type UTILITY
depends on "UPLOAD" (strong)
"PACKAGE" of type GLOBAL_TARGET
depends on "ALL_BUILD" (strong)
"UPLOAD" of type UTILITY
depends on "PACKAGE" (strong)
At least one of these targets is not a STATIC_LIBRARY.  Cyclic dependencies are allowed only among static libraries.
```

To do this I used to following code:

```
add_custom_target(UPLOAD ALL 
    COMMAND cmake -E echo "Should be post packging!"
)
add_dependencies(UPLOAD PACKAGE)
```

Is there some way to have the target to UPLOAD the PACKAGEd file?

Answer (score 3):

Create your own package target.

```
add_custom_target(mypackage
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "after packaging"
)
```

Comment: In this case, I have to configure CPack without using cmake?
Or is there a way to configure Cpack with cmake without including a whole cpackConfig (using the one generated by cmake include (cpack).

Otherwise, from cmake including cpack, I could have the dynamically generated CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME var in the sub command. Can it still be done?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Did you try what I posted?

Comment: Yes, I did. It outputs that the generator is not specified. This means that the "CPackConfig.cmake" file is not found, has I have guessed. It 's the configuration file for the packaging. (I removed include(cpack) from the cmake, cleaned and rebuilded). The fact is that I am configuring the CPackConfig file from the cmake. Some of the variables are not constant, like the files to copy in the package (dll, so, configuration and so on).
When a reused the old CPackConfig file, it did work, however only in release not in debug, and I would also only have the files set a the moment I took the file.

Comment: Well, after some looking around, it seams that the cmake_install.cmake file is called by cmake. The other configuration most be preset by a mean or the other. So we could use include (CPACK) to configure things, even if on with VS (at least) it adds an now "useless" PACKAGE project.

It could also be possible to have a CPackConfig.cmake.in that is configured for all generators. Not to sure about how to yet though.

Moreover, we should not call ${CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND} alone for visual studios if we want to make debug packages. We need to pass to it the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Upd: Since CMake 3.19 there is [`CPACK_POST_BUILD_SCRIPTS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html#variable:CPACK_POST_BUILD_SCRIPTS) to do any tasks after CPack produced packages.