# How to run script after the CPack build step?

Tags: cmake, cpack

I'd like to run a script after the 'package' target. `add_custom_command` with `POST_BUILD` doesn't work.

The `make package` command is expected to build, package and run the script. There should be no need for separate commands.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865761/cmake-post-package-step

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cmake : post-package step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865761/cmake-post-package-step)

Comment: @Raedwald, `make mypackage` from that answer doesn't even start building the project...